# Value and column operations in scala spark, how to use a value left of an operator with spark column?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to do some basic operations with Columns and Doubles and I can't figure out how to do it without creating a UDF.

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col
scala> import spark.implicits._

scala> val df = Seq(("A", 1), ("B", 2), ("C", 3)).toDF("col1", "col2")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [col1: string, col2: int]
```

I want to find the reciprocal of col2, I would think to do that would be something like:

```
scala> df.withColumn("col3", 1/col("col2")).show
```

But that give this error:

```
<console>:30: error: overloaded method value / with alternatives:
  (x: Double)Double <and>
  (x: Float)Float <and>
  (x: Long)Long <and>
  (x: Int)Int <and>
  (x: Char)Int <and>
  (x: Short)Int <and>
  (x: Byte)Int
 cannot be applied to (org.apache.spark.sql.Column)
       df.withColumn("col3", 1/col("col2")).show
```

Basically saying that you can't perform division (or any other operator) with a Double on the left hand side and a Column on the right. The only way I have been able to figure out how to do this is to create a UDF and apply it like this:

```
scala> def reciprocal(x: Double) : Double = {1/x}
reciprocal: (x: Double)Double

scala> val reciprocalUDF = spark.sqlContext.udf.register(
       "reciprocalUDF", reciprocal _)

scala> df.withColumn("col3", reciprocalUDF(col("col2"))).show
+----+----+------------------+
|col1|col2|              col3|
+----+----+------------------+
|   A|   1|               1.0|
|   B|   2|               0.5|
|   C|   3|0.3333333333333333|
+----+----+------------------+
```

But really? Are UDFs the only way to do this sort of thing? I don't want to create a UDF every time I have to do some simple operation like division.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use literal `Column`

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit

lit(1) / col("col2")
```